# Google Map Gets Cropped When Using Display:Inherit;

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am trying to hide/show Google Maps by switching between `display:none;` and `display:inherit;`. When I apply `display:inherit` to Google Maps, part of the map gets cropped and I am unsure why. How would I fix this while still using `display:none;`?

[Link to example](http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/test.html)

```
//HTML
<button id="toggleMap">Toggle Google Map</button>
<button id="toggleImage">Toggle Image</button>

<div id="image">
  <img src="http://jdm-digital.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/google-jquery-opt-465x346.jpg">
</div>

<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:500px; display:none;">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%;"></div>
</div>


//JavaScript
$('#toggleImage').click(function() {
  $('#image').css('display', 'inherit');
  $('#map').css('display', 'none');
});

$('#toggleMap').click(function() {
  $('#image').css('display', 'none');
  $('#map').css('display', 'inherit');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a map while it's hidden the API doesn't know how big it should be because the browser reports it has zero size. The API only loads enough tiles for a zero-size map, and positions the centre at (0,0) — the top-left corner.

When you unhide the map, tell the API to get the new size by triggering the resize event:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize')
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) — scroll down to Events.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is much cleaner then mine.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you can give `display:block` instead of `display:inherit`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use `$('#map').append(mapHTML);` whenever `#toggleMap` was clicked. This way allowed for the map to be created whenever `#map` becomes visible.

I feel that this approach is sort of hack-ish; If anyone has an alternative solution I'd definitely like to know about it.

```
//HTML
<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:500px; display:none;"></div>


//JavaScript
$('#toggleMap').click(function() {
  $('#image').css('display', 'none');
  $('#map').css('display', 'inherit');

  var mapHTML = "<div id=\"map_canvas\" style=\"height:100%;\"></div>";
  $('#map').append(mapHTML);
  googleMap();  //Google Map's initialize() that would create the map
});
```