# Google map in wordpress plugin

Tags: google-maps, wordpress

I have used **Draggable Markers**  for google map

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html.

When I am using the smaple code on a simple html or php page then it's looking good same as on the link, but when I am using it in a wordpress plugin then the pointer of the map is not comeing in center and also the full map.
it looks like

http://www.screencast.com/users/Bidyut/folders/Default/media/10451777-2b22-40af-aa3e-c16d27e8ecf6

then when I am clicking on firebug of mozilla then the full map is coming but the red bellon pointer is not in the center. I can not understand the problem.

Do any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Standard answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606666/1204258

If you edit your question to include the URL where you're having trouble, it may be possible to give advice about where the single line of code needs to go. As it's a plugin it may involve changing the PHP code: which plugin are you using?